# Override Launch Screen File with Launch Images while remaining optimized for iPhone 6/6+?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

Other posts on SO address how to disable the Launch Screen with Launch Images, but these all require deleting the Launch Screen, which causes the app to no longer be considered "optimized" for the iPhone 6/6+?

How can you optimize an app for the iPhone 6/6+ while overriding the Launch Screen and using Launch Images? The deployment target is 7.1.

Comment: Thanks for this question I didn't know that Apple wouldn't consider the app optimized for the iPhone 6(+) if you don't have a launch screen. Now that I know this I'll just make my Launch Screen one big imageView and load the UIImage from the app launch screen assets.

Comment: how do you dynamically choose the right image? you're going to subclass imageView?

Comment: I'll probably use UIDevice or UIScreen to figure out which Launch Screen to display.